# xsl-fo transformation much slower with Java 11 instead of 1.8

Tags: java, awt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

After updating my program to Java 11, the transformations of an XML using xsl-fo (AWT renderer) have become much slower:
Java 11: 90 seconds
Java 1.8: 5 seconds

I've not tried it with Java 9 or 10.

There was no code and no stylesheet change between the run with Java 11 and 1.8.

I'm using org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop in version 2.3.

Also with Saxon-HE 9.9.1-5 (instead of Xalan) there was unfortunately no performance improvement.

Via profiling and debugging it looks like the code line 284 in the class org.apache.fop.layoutmgr.table.TableContentLayoutManager consumes the time:

```
nextRowGroupElems = rowGroupLM.getNextKnuthElements(context, alignment, bodyType);
```

So the culprit is Apache FOP using AWT. Using MIME_PDF instead of MIME_FOP_AWT_PREVIEW is much faster: 5 seconds vs 90 seconds.

The profiler (JProfiler) shows java.awt.EventDispatchThread as hot spot for Java 11. So maybe it is an AWT problem.

The relevant Code to reproduce:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMResult;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXResult;

import org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopConfParser;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactoryBuilder;
import org.apache.fop.apps.MimeConstants;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class MyTransform {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Document xmlDoc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new FileInputStream("my_xml.xml"));
        Document xslDoc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("my_xsl.xsl")); 

        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new DOMSource(xslDoc));

        DOMSource xmlDomSource = new DOMSource(xmlDoc);
        DOMResult domResult = new DOMResult();
        transformer.transform(xmlDomSource, domResult);

        Source src = new DOMSource(domResult.getNode());
        Result res = new SAXResult(createFopFactory().newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_FOP_AWT_PREVIEW, getDisplayAgent()).getDefaultHandler());

        TransformerFactory factory = javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        transformer = factory.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(src, res);

        transformer.transform(src, res); // took with Java 11 90 seconds and with Java 1.8 5 seconds
    }

    private static FopFactory createFopFactory() throws SAXException, IOException {
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("fop_configuration.xml");
        FopConfParser parser = new FopConfParser(resource.getInputStream(), resource.getURI()); //parsing configuration
        FopFactoryBuilder builder = parser.getFopFactoryBuilder(); //building the factory with the user options
        return builder.build();
    }

    private static FOUserAgent getDisplayAgent() throws SAXException, IOException {
        FopFactory fopFactory = createFopFactory();
        FOUserAgent displayAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
        MyAWTRendererMaker maker = new MyAWTRendererMaker();
        displayAgent.getRendererFactory().addRendererMaker(maker);
        MyAWTRenderer displayRenderer = new MyAWTRenderer(displayAgent);
        displayAgent.setRendererOverride(displayRenderer);
        return displayAgent;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're probably going to have to do some initial investigation yourself to work out which component or which stage of the process is the culprit. And if you want anyone to help, you're going to have to provide sufficient material for them to reproduce the problem on their own machine. Performance issues like this often depend on some peculiar quirk of your workload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by first generating a PDF and then displaying it in a dialog box of ICEpdf instead of Apache FOP. It seems that using the output format MIME_FOP_AWT_PREVIEW causes the problems, instead I now use MIME_PDF.